Why sentencepiece tokenizer in nllb returns id's that differ by 1 when I specify model name or file?
When I'm using hf tokenizers and specify the model by name facebook/nllb-200-distilled-600M I get such tokens: 256047, 30311, 104, 253990 and so on. But when I take the sentencepiece.bpe.model from the repo and load it as a file I get this: 30310, 103, 253989. I understand that the first token is the language that this model requires for knowing the translation, but why the next tokens differ by 1? The input string is "English (eng_Latn) is set as the default language from which to translate." And this difference is consistent on the whole string.

What is the input string?

This implies that the hf tokenizer has an additional token in its vocabulary, which is not present in the sentencepiece.bpe.model tokenizer. You can compare the tokens in both tokenizer vocabs, to identify the token responsible for this.
